# Failed to put an update from React to the MySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I got a project from my friend, the project uses React.js, Node.js, Express.js and MySQL technologies. And when I work on the CRUD section, I only managed to make the input update, but I can't make changes to the database.

**This is my React code:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { InputText } from "primereact/inputtext";
import { Button } from "primereact/button";

export class EditFK extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      id: "",
      nama: null,
      fakultas: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3210/fakultas").then(getdata => {
      this.setState({
        fakultas: getdata.data
      });
    });
  }

  saveData() {
    axios
      .put(`http://localhost:3210/fakultas/edit/${this.params}`)
      .then(postdata => {
        this.setState({
          dataTableValue: postdata.data
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="p-grid p-fluid">
        <div className="p-col-12 card card-w-title">
          <h1>Edit Fakultas</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="p-col-6">
          <div className="card card-w-title">
            <h4>Ubah Fakultas</h4>
            <div className="p-grid">
              <div className="p-col-12 p-md-6">
                <InputText placeholder="Nama" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="p-col-12">
          <div className="p-col-3">
            <Button
              label="Update"
              icon="pi pi-pencil"
              onClick={this.saveData()}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**This is my backend code:**

```
//get fakultas by id
app.get("/fakultas/:id", (req, res) => {
  var sql = `SELECT * FROM fakultas WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;
  db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

//edit fakultas by id
app.put("/fakultas/edit/:id", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  var data = {
    id: req.body.id,
    nama: req.body.nama
  };
  var sql = `UPDATE fakultas set ? WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;
  db.query(sql, data, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      res.send({
        status: `Data Berhasil di Update`,
        id: req.body.id,
        nama: req.body.nama
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**The link below is column from fakultas table:**

[fakultas table column screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzgPh.png)

Comment: add this after .then in axios to debug- `.catch(e => console.log(e)); `

Comment: where exactly to put that code?

Comment: axios.put().then().catch()

Comment: It's said:
PUT http://localhost:3210/fakultas/edit/undefined net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: try clearing your browser cache. Check server connection. Look into network tab in the console. Check if it is sending any error codes. Try to find the fix  of the corresponding error code

Answer (score 0):

I know really the basics about sql queries, but I think you should replace the question mark with the name of the column you want to set:

```
  var sql = `UPDATE fakultas set columnName = newValue WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;
```

Plus: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636456/javascript-binding-sql-results-to-a-function) for you, I think the code posted by the user is what you need

Comment: I already change it to ` var sql = `UPDATE fakultas set nama = ${req.params.nama} WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`; `
But still can't update database

Comment: check if you're passing the right id, or if arrived from the client an undefined